# IMDB SPARQL Endpoint - Movies LIKE operator

Tags: php, rdf, sparql, dbpedia, linkedmdb

I'm currently working with different SPARQL endpoints and looking to query the IMDB endpoint for movies by title. I have already come up with the following query for DBPedia.

```
SELECT DISTINCT film_title
WHERE {
   ?film_title rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film> .
   ?film_title dbpprop:name ?label . FILTER langMatches(lang(?label), "en")
   ?film_title rdfs:comment ?comment . FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?comment), "en")) .
   FILTER (REGEX(STR(?film_title), "The Big Lebowski", "i")) .
} LIMIT 10
```

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to structure the query for IMDB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Your query is not legal and after fixing it there are no results from DBpedia

Your query doesn't work on DBpedia.  It's missing `?` in `select distinct film_title`, and even if you add that in, you don't get any results.  I expect that you actually want something like

```sql
select distinct ?film where  {
   ?film a dbpedia-owl:Film ; 
         rdfs:label ?label .
   filter contains( ?label, "The Big Lebowski" )
}
limit 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20?film%20where%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20?film%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aFilm%20;%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20filter%20contains%28%20?label,%20%22The%20Big%20Lebowski%22%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%2010%0D%0A&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

### IMDB does not have a SPARQL endpoint

I don't know of any IMDB SPARQL endpoint, and a Google search for `imdb sparql endpoint` doesn't turn one up.  I'll go out on a limb and assume that you're talking about the LinkedMDB SPARQL endpoint, since it has some information about some films that are also in the IMDB.  It has a SPARQL endpointt, as well as a [SNORQL explorer](http://www.linkedmdb.org/snorql/) where you can test queries.

### A query that works on DBpedia *and* LinkedMDB

If you also browse the LinkedMDB pages for films, you can find out what properties they use.  E.g., from the page for [*The Magician*](http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/film/1562), you can see that LinkedMDB also uses rdfs:label to indicate titles.  The relevant type isn't dbpedia-owl:Film, though, but movie:film, which is `<http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/film>`.

Now, the LinkedMDB endpoint doesn't use SPARQL 1.1, so you can't use the `contains` function, but you can still use regex.  Since we know that *The Magician* has an entry there (it doesn't look like *The Big Lebowski* does), let's look at a similar query that retrieves it:

```sql
select distinct ?film where  {
   ?film a movie:film ;
         rdfs:label ?label .
   filter regex( str(?label), "The Magician", "i")
}
limit 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://www.linkedmdb.org/snorql/?query=%20%20%20%20select%20distinct%20?film%20where%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20?film%20a%20movie%3afilm%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20filter%20regex%28%20str%28?label%29,%20%22The%20Magician%22,%20%22i%22%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20limit%2010&prefixes=PREFIX%20owl%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20xsd%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdf%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3a%20%3Chttp://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20oddlinker%3a%20%3Chttp://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/oddlinker/%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20map%3a%20%3Cfile:/C:/d2r-server-0.4/mapping.n3#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20db%3a%20%3Chttp://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20skos%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dc%3a%20%3Chttp://purl.org/dc/terms/%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20movie%3a%20%3Chttp://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/%3E%0D%0A)

Now you can ask whether there's a query that would work on both LinkedMDB and on DBpedia, and sure enough there is:

```sql
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix movie: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/>

select distinct ?film where  {
  { ?film a movie:film       } union 
  { ?film a dbpedia-owl:Film }
  ?film rdfs:label ?label .
  filter regex( str(?label), "The Magician", "i")
}
limit 10
```

[LinkedMDB SPARQL results (1 film)](http://www.linkedmdb.org/snorql/?query=prefix%20dbpedia-owl%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20movie%3a%20%3Chttp://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20distinct%20?film%20where%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20?film%20a%20movie%3afilm%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20union%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20?film%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aFilm%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20?film%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20regex%28%20str%28?label%29,%20%22The%20Magician%22,%20%22i%22%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%2010&prefixes=PREFIX%20owl%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20xsd%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdfs%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20rdf%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3a%20%3Chttp://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20oddlinker%3a%20%3Chttp://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/oddlinker/%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20map%3a%20%3Cfile:/C:/d2r-server-0.4/mapping.n3#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20db%3a%20%3Chttp://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbpedia%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/property/%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20skos%3a%20%3Chttp://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dc%3a%20%3Chttp://purl.org/dc/terms/%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20movie%3a%20%3Chttp://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/%3E%0D%0A)
[DBpedia SPARQL results  (10 films)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=prefix%20dbpedia-owl%3a%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20movie%3a%20%3Chttp://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20distinct%20?film%20where%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20?film%20a%20movie%3afilm%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20union%20%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20?film%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3aFilm%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20?film%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20regex%28%20str%28?label%29,%20%22The%20Magician%22,%20%22i%22%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%2010&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Thank you for such an informative and detailed answer. Also thanks for highlighting the syntax error. Yes I was referring to the LinkedMDB SPARQL endpoint sorry about the confusion.